# Объект не удаляется Unity3d 2d

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-android

Я хочу чтобы при столкновении один Объект удалялся

Ошибка

> Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid dataq loss. If you really want to remove an asset use DestroyImmeduate (theObject, true);

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class shield : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject slot_1;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    if (other.CompareTag("Finish")) {   
        DestroyProjectile();
    }
}

void DestroyProjectile() {
    Destroy(slot_1);
}

}
```

Comment: На какой объект ссылается slot_1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, у вас возникает такая ошибка потому что вы пытаетесь выполнить `Destroy()` к ассету (например префабу из файлов вашего проекта), тогда как его можно применить к `GameObject`, который создан на сцене в запущенной игре. То есть, вы можете применить эту операцию к конкретному объекту в вашей игре, а не ресурсу этой игры. 
Похожий вопрос есть на [официальном форуме юнити](https://answers.unity.com/questions/650152/destroying-assets-is-not-permitted-to-avoid-data-l-2.html).

Например, если вы сначала создите объект с помощью [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) из префаба, то далее сможете его уничтожить:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class shield : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject slot_1;
GameObject projectiileClone;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    if (other.CompareTag("Finish")) {   
        projectileClone = (GameObject)Instantiate(slot_1);
        DestroyProjectile();
    }
}

void DestroyProjectile() {
    Destroy(projectileClone);
}

}
```

Данный код создаст и сразу уничтожит объект. По этому код создания объекта вам нужно перенести в нужное вам место.